# How to create a list with clickable id in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a list of array items from a json file,more list the list you find on google plus,but i am new to programming and dont know how to do it using javascript.Please help.I tried the following but im getting a blank page;

```
var records = {
            "states": [
                {
                    "name": "johor",
                    "command": "view_johor"
                },

                {
                    "name": "selangor",
                    "command": "view_selangor"
                },

                {
                    "name": "melaka",
                    "command": "view_melaka"
                },

                {
                    "name": "kuala lumpur",
                    "command": "view_kl"
                },

                {
                    "name": "penang",
                    "command": "view_penang"
                }
            ]
        };

        $.each(records.states, function (key, val) {
            $('#ul').append($('<li>').text('name: ' + val.name + ', command: ' + val.command));
        });
```

and html:

```
 <ul id="ul"></ul>
```

And i dont understand how list.js and data.js work as list plugins.I managed to display a list from json file using handlebars but gave up along the way as i couldnt figure out the onclick item display content of selected item in handlebars.Now im trying to do it the old fashioned way,using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `each()` function in your example, but you didn't tag `jQuery`. It's such a simple case that I would suggest you to use pure javascript.

```js
var records = {states:[{name:"johor",command:"view_johor"},{name:"selangor",command:"view_selangor"},{name:"melaka",command:"view_melaka"},{name:"kuala lumpur",command:"view_kl"},{name:"penang",command:"view_penang"}]},

    elem = document.getElementById('ul');  //get 'ul' element from the DOM
      records.states.forEach(function(v) { //iterate over array in JSON
        var li = document.createElement('li'); //create 'li' element
        li.innerHTML = 'name: ' + v.name; //assign your data to each 'li'
        elem.appendChild(li); //append 'li' to the 'ul' element
    });
    
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
Array.from(elems).forEach((v,i) => v.addEventListener('click', function(){
  Array.from(elems).forEach((c,k) => {c.style.background = 'transparent'; c.innerHTML = 'name: ' + records.states[k].name;});
  this.innerHTML = 'name: ' + records.states[i].name + ', command: ' + records.states[i].command; 
  this.style.background = '#E3F6CE';
}));
```

```html
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Comment: thank you.This works perfectly.Now how do i do the onclick display command for each item clicked?

Comment: @AngelaDutchan Tell me exactly what do you want to happen, if you click on each `li`.

Comment: so basically the list should only contain name and command should display when item of the list is selected.More like view more.Sorry for bothering you,im learning...did this already with handlebars js,,but handlebars is proving to be difficult with onclick li..."for each li"

Comment: thanks..im also trying to research,but the problem is,i dont know the correct terminology to search for:i searched for javascript list tutorials,javascript array list..and im hitting a wall